# Animate android views in order

Tags: android, android-animation

For a blackjack game I'm making, I need the card to translate to the dealer position from the pile, then to the player position, so I made a general method for it.

```
   private void dealHand() {

    animateCard(dealer_iv_1);
    animateCard(dealer_iv_2);
    animateCard(player_iv_1);
    animateCard(player_iv_2);
}

private void animateCard(View v) {

    animated_card_iv.animate().x(v.getX()).y(v.getY()).setDuration(1000).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            animated_card_iv.setX(pile_iv.getX());
            animated_card_iv.setY(pile_iv.getY());
        }
    }).start();
}
```

As it's written right now it's obviously gonna animate only one card to player_iv_2.

I don't want to wait 1000 millis between animateCard() calls using a Timer or CountDownTimer. 
What I would want is for it to be something like this:

```
 private void dealHand() {

    animateCard(dealer_iv_1).wait();
    animateCard(dealer_iv_2).wait();
    animateCard(player_iv_1).wait();
    animateCard(player_iv_2);
}
```

so animateCard() needs to return a type and let me know when it's done. how is this possible?

So far this is what I got:

```
private void dealHand() {

    animateCard(dealer_iv_1, 0);
    animateCard(player_iv_1, 1010);
    animateCard(player_iv_2, 2010);


}

private void animateCard(View v, long startDelay) {

    final ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(104, 149));
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.back0);
    iv.setX(pile_iv.getX());
    iv.setY(pile_iv.getY());
    ((RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.pile_layout)).addView(iv);

    iv.animate().x(v.getX()).y(v.getY()).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(startDelay).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ((RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.pile_layout)).removeView(iv);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

As you can see I'm now creating 3 ImageViews every time dealHand() is called, and removing each of them after they finish animate, I just gotta ask if I'm doing it properly since I tried calling dealHand() about 50 times which produced 150 of ImageViews, I saw it took about 1.5Mb of RAM in the profiler, this 1.5Mb didn't clean up, even when I called System.gc().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, ditch the `animation` library and use the [ObjectAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) library.  It's newer and 100x more useful.

Then, use an [AnimatorSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html) to play the animations. `AnimatorSets` can play animations either sequentially or in order. You can just create your animations and either use the `AnimatorSet#Builter` or the `AnimatorSet#playSequentially` to play them all in order.

Then, don't worry about the garbage collection and cleanup. Just remove them from View and the garbage collector will clean them up when it's ready. However, you may consider a more efficient strategy by recycling and re-using the ImageViews each time. That way you're not re-building them constantly. Also, it prevents a lot of heavy, unnecessary garbage collecting. This would only need to be considered if the animations happen frequently.